# Incorrect URL's being generated

Tags: error, url, pagination

I have an ee site, and in google webmaster tools it's generating some really random urls - and causing a big problem with duplicate title tags - but I can't figure out where they are coming from - an example url is:

http://www.oceanindependence.com/yacht-sales/yachts-for-sale/caprice/P12

but then google seems to keep finding more links the same but with different pagination on the end, ie /P108 /P216 etc... I have added in a 301 redirect to get the page to point correctly, but this doesn't fix where the link is coming from in the first place

The weird part is, that the 3rd segment should be the pagination eg ( http://www.oceanindependence.com/yacht-sales/yachts-for-sale/P12 ) but somehow an extra segment is being added in before this and google is finding it from somewhere

In the template for yachts-for-sale, the only link code is:  - which for me all seems to work correctly

Am hoping someone may have encountered something like this before and maybe have a solution?

I am using ee 2.7.0 and structure (but I don't think this is structure related)

Cheers Jonny

Answer (score 3):

I just check your site using [Integrity](http://peacockmedia.co.uk/integrity/) and it looks like you don't have this urls any more. Possible you had something in your old templates (I can see that Google cache had another design for pages like /caprice/P12).

I believe soon all old links will be removed by Google because of Status : 301. Just need to wait.

I saw also that you start using

```
<link rel="canonical" href=""/>
```

which will protect your urls from duplication.